# Pandas: How to conditionally assign multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to replace negative values with `nan` for only certain columns. The simplest way could be:

```
for col in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
    df.loc[df[col ] < 0, col] = np.nan
```

`df` could have many columns and I only want to do this to specific columns.

Is there a way to do this in one line? Seems like this should be easy but I have not been able to figure out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think you'll get much simpler than this:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.arange(-5, 2), 'b': np.arange(-5, 2), 'c': np.arange(-5, 2), 'd': np.arange(-5, 2), 'e': np.arange(-5, 2)})
>>> df
   a  b  c  d  e
0 -5 -5 -5 -5 -5
1 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4
2 -3 -3 -3 -3 -3
3 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2
4 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
5  0  0  0  0  0
6  1  1  1  1  1
>>> df[df[cols] < 0] = np.nan
>>> df
     a    b    c  d  e
0  NaN  NaN  NaN -5 -5
1  NaN  NaN  NaN -4 -4
2  NaN  NaN  NaN -3 -3
3  NaN  NaN  NaN -2 -2
4  NaN  NaN  NaN -1 -1
5  0.0  0.0  0.0  0  0
6  1.0  1.0  1.0  1  1
```

Answer (score 8):

use `loc` and `where`

```
cols = ['a', 'b', 'c']
df.loc[:, cols] = df[cols].where(df[cols].where.ge(0), np.nan)
```

***demonstration***

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 5), columns=list('abcde'))
df
```

[image]

```
cols = list('abc')
df.loc[:, cols] = df[cols].where(df[cols].ge(0), np.nan)
df
```

[image]

---

You could speed it up with numpy

```
df[cols] = np.where(df[cols] < 0, np.nan, df[cols])
```

to do the same thing.

---

***timing***

```
def gen_df(n):
    return pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(n, 5), columns=list('abcde'))
```

since assignment is an important part of this, I create the `df` from scratch each loop.  I also added the timing for `df` creation.

for `n = 10000`

[image]

for `n = 100000`

[image]

Comment: @jezrael nice catch

Answer (score 5):

Here's a way:

```
df[df.columns.isin(['a', 'b', 'c']) & (df < 0)] = np.nan
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `np.where` to achieve this:

```
In [47]:
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,5), columns=list('abcde'))
df

Out[47]:
          a         b         c         d         e
0  0.616829 -0.933365 -0.735308  0.665297 -1.333547
1  0.069158  2.266290 -0.068686 -0.787980 -0.082090
2  1.203311  1.661110 -1.227530 -1.625526  0.045932
3 -0.247134 -1.134400  0.355436  0.787232 -0.474243
4  0.131774  0.349103 -0.632660 -1.549563  1.196455

In [48]:    
df[['a','b','c']] = np.where(df[['a','b','c']] < 0, np.NaN, df[['a','b','c']])
df

Out[48]:
          a         b         c         d         e
0  0.616829       NaN       NaN  0.665297 -1.333547
1  0.069158  2.266290       NaN -0.787980 -0.082090
2  1.203311  1.661110       NaN -1.625526  0.045932
3       NaN       NaN  0.355436  0.787232 -0.474243
4  0.131774  0.349103       NaN -1.549563  1.196455
```

Answer (score 3):

Sure, just pick your desired columns out of the mask:

```
(df < 0)[['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

You can use this mask in `df[(df < 0)[['a', 'b', 'c']]] = np.nan`.

Answer (score 1):

If it has to be a one-liner:

```
df[['a', 'b', 'c']] = df[['a', 'b', 'c']].apply(lambda c: [x>0 and x or np.nan for x in c])
```